# Elisp Check if Current Point is on the line after a given point

Tags: elisp

I am trying to write an elisp function to take a region of text, quote each line, and put commas at the end of every line except for the last one.

This would be an example transformation:

From

```
Aaaa Bbbb CCcc 
DDddd eeeee ffffffff
ggggg hhh iiii
```

To:

```
"Aaaa Bbbb CCcc", 
"DDddd eeeee ffffffff",
"ggggg hhh iiii"
```

This is what I have so far:

```
(defun quote-lines (p1 p2)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (while (<= (point) p2) ; Would like to check if we are on
               ; the line after p2
         (move-beginning-of-line nil)
         (insert "\"")
         (move-end-of-line nil)
         (insert "\",")
         (forward-line))
    (move-end-of-line nil)
    (delete-char 1)))
```

Any help making my elisp function more idiomatic would also be appreciated.

Comment: Looks OK, except that you fail to use `p1` and that `move-beginning/end-of-line` is meant for interactive use only (the version without "move-" is preferred in Lisp code).  You could use `(forward-line 0)` before the loop, so that you know that point is at the beginning of line already at the beginning of each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say much about idiomatic.
I just write whatever works at the moment.
Here's a fix for your code (you forgot `goto-char` so it doesn't work
if you select region in reverse):

```
(defun quote-lines (p1 p2)
  (interactive "r")
  (deactivate-mark)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char p1)
    (move-beginning-of-line 1)
    (while (< (point) p2)
      (insert "\"")
      (move-end-of-line 1)
      (insert "\",")
      (forward-line))
    (backward-delete-char 1)))
```

I see that you went with a while loop. That is indeed more efficient.
Depending on circumstances, you could go the functional way.
It's more beautiful, but less efficient, I guess.

```
(defun quote-lines-1 ()
  (interactive )
  (let* ((beg (if (region-active-p)
                  (region-beginning)
                (point-min)))
         (end (if (region-active-p)
                  (region-end)
                (point-max)))
         (str (buffer-substring beg end)))
    (delete-region beg end)
    (insert
     (mapconcat (lambda (x) (format "\"%s\"" x))
                (split-string str "\n")
                ",\n"))))
```

Comment: On a large enough region this will misbehave because `p2` will not refer to the right buffer position any more after all those insertions.  So either change the code to use a marker for `p2`, or change the code to start at `p2` and move backward to `p1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
(defun quote-lines (beg end)
 "Put double-quotes around each line in the region. Put a comma after each line.
Quote each whole line that contains part of the region."
  (interactive "r")
  (setq beg  (save-excursion (goto-char beg) (line-beginning-position))
        end  (save-excursion (goto-char end) (line-end-position)))
  (let ((lines  (mapconcat (lambda (line) (format "\"%s\"" line))
                           (split-string (buffer-substring beg end) "\n" t)
                           ",\n")))
    (delete-region beg end)
    (insert lines)))
```

First, the region is in effect extended to include whole lines.

Then the region is split into lines (`split-string`), and each line is quoted and then followed by a comma (`mapconcat`).

Then the region is replaced with desired result.